# profiling TensorFlow dataset

Tags: tensorflow, profiling, tensorboard

I'm trying to reproduce the `TF` profiling example from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance_analysis#synchronous_and_asynchronous_transformations).

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.profiler.experimental.start('log_folder')

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: x)
dataset = dataset.repeat(2)
dataset = dataset.batch(5)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)
tf.profiler.experimental.stop()
```

however, I'm receiving a *events.out.tfevents.1689241158.hostname.profile-empty* file in *log_folder* and unable to explore results via `TensorBoard`

Comment: Kindly check your Tensorflow version supports the profiler. Make sure when you’re using a version of Tensorflow that supports the profiler.
You can check your tensor flow version by using this code.
`Import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)`.